# Showing two spaces are homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology

So I understand the basics about homotopy, I know a punctured disk or $\mathbb{R}- \{ 0 \}$ are homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^1$. This can be shown using the deformation retract $d(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$. The problem is that we have been told certain sets are homotopy equivalent and I can only state that *visually*.

I would like to to know which explicit deformation retract or functions prove X and $\mathbb{S}^2$ are homotopy equivalent, where X is defined as:
$$X= \mathbb{S}^2 \cup \mathbb{D}_2 \cup \mathbb{I} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$$
Where:
$$\mathbb{S}^2=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=1 \} $$ $$\mathbb{D}_2=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | y^2+z^2=4 , x=0 \} -\{ (0,2,0), (0,-2,0) \} $$
$$ \mathbb{I}= \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 1\leqslant |Z| \leqslant2,  x=y=0 \} $$

Comment: Are you sure that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^2$? If I am not mistaken, $X$ is not simply connected because the circle of radius $2$ in the $yz$-plane is not homotopic to a point. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LukasGeyer: Note that $D_2$ has two points deleted. What you describe is not actually a loop in $X$. This is indeed homotopy equivalent to $S^2$.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Oops, I misread, somehow I thought that $\mathbb{I}$ contains those two points, but now I see it does not. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I would define the deformation retract in pieces.  First, collapse $D_2$ down to $S^2\ cup I$, then collapse $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ does not contain $(0,\pm 2,0)$, you can write points on $\mathbb{D}_2$ in polar coordinates as $(0,\cos t, \sin t)$ with $0 < |t| < \pi$. So $\mathbb{D}_2$ can be retracted by a linear homotopy in polar coordinates to the points $(0,0,\pm 2)$. (I.e., retract the $t$-interval $(-\pi, 0)$ to the point $-\pi/2$, and the interval $(0,\pi)$ to $\pi/2$.)

Now this deformation retract from $X$ to $\mathbb{S}^2 \cup \mathbb{I}$ can be followed by a linear (in the $z$-coordinate) deformation retract of $\mathbb{I}$ to the points $(0,0,\pm 1)$.